# Javascript get URL params, then trigger click on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, get

I got an GET request on a webpage, with multidimensional checkboxes.
The GET request would look like this:

```
&company_state[AKERSHUS]=AKERSHUS&company_state[AKERSHUS][]=ASKER&company_state[SOGN+OG+FJORDANE]=SOGN+OG+FJORDANE&company_state[SOGN+OG+FJORDANE][]=ASKVOLL
```

As you can see, `company_state` is an array, wich again contains an array of values.

Is it possible to use jQuery or plain JS to grab the URL parameters, and trigger a click on the checkboxes with the same name (company_state, company_municipality) and value?

I tried using this, but this doesn't seem to work in this purpose to grab the params.

```
function getQueryParams(qs) {
  qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");
  var params = {},
    tokens,
    re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;
  while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
    params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])] = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
  }
  return params;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:[image]

Gives this result in console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can parse query string as array, 
and then iterate over array and extract key and value.

Code is like this:

```
    function getQueryParameters(str) {
      return (str || document.location.search).replace(/(^\?)/,'').split("&").map(
        function(n){
          return n = n.split("="),this[n[0]] = n[1],this;
        }.bind({}))[0];
  }

var url = "&company_state[AKERSHUS]=AKERSHUS&company_state[AKERSHUS[]=ASKER&company_state[SOGN+OG+FJORDANE]=SOGN+OG+FJORDANE&company_state[SOGN+OG+FJORDANE][]=ASKVOLL";

var arr = getQueryParameters(url);


for(var a in arr){
  console.log("key:" , a.substr('company_state'.length), "   value:" ,  arr[a]);
}
```

You have [here](http://jsbin.com/nerejihene/edit?html,js,output) a live example.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's working like it should.
The company_state[value] may also have a array of values.
Like so: 

`var url = "&company_state[AKERSHUS]=AKERSHUS&company_state[AKERSHUS[]=ASKER&company_state[SOGN+OG+FJORDANE]=SOGN+OG+FJORDANE&company_state[SOGN+OG+FJORDANE][]=ASKVOLL&company_state[SOGN+OG+FJORDANE][]=EID"`

As you can see, SOGN+OG+FJORDANE has two child values.

Comment: Can you edit your post with an example of the result?

Comment: Okay, I fixed it another way using old input data (Laravel) to check the checkboxes.